# Import Flex RTE HtmlText to TLF TextFlow

Tags: html, apache-flex, import, rte, tlf

I am working as a developer on a Flex/Air application and we are using the buggy Flex RTE (RichTextEditor) to let the user manage his notes. At the moment I am trying to evaluate how costly it would be for us to build a new text component using the TLF (Text Layout Framework).

Really important is the question if we can import the HTML text, produced by the RTE straight away. I know that there are some limitations regarding lists with TLF 1.1, but does it work in general?

I have just tried to grab some HTML formatted text from RTE like:

```
var htmlText:String = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="defaultFont" SIZE="14" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">1hr run on Wednesday - feeling ok!</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>'
```

when I pass this to the TextConverter like this:

```
var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlText, TextConverter.HTML_FORMAT);
```

The Flash Player throws an exception. I also tried to wrap the text with

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

, but same issue. So it does not seem to work straight away. What are you experiences? This is really critical to us.

UPDATE 1:

When I try to import the HTML like above (same variable declaration) I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at flashx.textLayout.formats::TextLayoutFormatValueHolder/apply()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_core\src\flashx\textLayout\formats\TextLayoutFormatValueHolder.as:357]
at HtmlImporter$/parseTextFormat()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\HtmlImporter.as:307]
at BaseTextLayoutImporter/parseObject()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\BaseTextLayoutImporter.as:464]
at BaseTextLayoutImporter/parseFlowGroupElementChildren()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\BaseTextLayoutImporter.as:419]
at HtmlImporter$/parseHtmlContainer()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\HtmlImporter.as:269]
at BaseTextLayoutImporter/parseObject()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\BaseTextLayoutImporter.as:464]
at HtmlImporter/importFromXML()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\HtmlImporter.as:142]
at HtmlImporter/importFromString()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\HtmlImporter.as:130]
at BaseTextLayoutImporter/importToFlow()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\BaseTextLayoutImporter.as:73]
at flashx.textLayout.conversion::TextConverter$/importToFlow()[C:\Vellum\branches\v1\1.0\dev\textLayout_conversion\src\flashx\textLayout\conversion\TextConverter.as:87]
at TLFTestApp/init()[/Users/Arne/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4/TLFRichTextEditor/src/TLFTestApp.mxml:29] <-- // executing TextConverter.importToFlow(htmlText, TextConverter.HTML_FORMAT);
```

Meanwhile I removed the  tags and it works, but the question still remains.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html

There are three constants for the format, none of which seems to be what you used:

```
PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT
TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT
TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT
```

Also, the format of the following "html" code looks more like TLF-formatted XML than HTML.

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="defaultFont" SIZE="14" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">1hr run on Wednesday - feeling ok!</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```